# KCachegrind: command not found

Tags: performance, valgrind, kcachegrind

I installed valgrind on **Centos** using this command:

```
yum install valgrind kcachegrind graphviz
```

I then used the callgrind tool for my c++ program. It generated its callgrind.out.42424 file.

Now, I want to open this file on KCacheGrind using this command:

```
   kcachegrind ./callgrind.out.42424
```

but terminal says

bash kcachegrind : command not found

I don't know why I am getting this error whereas I installed it. Do I need to be in specific directory to run this command?

Comment: What does `rpm -q -l kcachegrind` say?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz It says no package kcachegrind available. I now did yum install kcachegrind but it says no package kcachegrind available.

Comment: What is the correct command to install this?

Comment: Google suggests “kdesdk” for CentOS

Answer (score 9):

```
sudo yum install kdesdk valgrind graphviz
```

Comment: You may need to enable repos if this doesn't work. The kdesdk lives in the rhel-7-server-optional-rpms repo which is disabled in the default RHEL install. To enable the repo run sudo subscription-manager repos --enable=rhel-7-server-optional-rpms